# ¿Cúal es es equivalente de .get() de Jquery en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito que mi video al iniciar y al terminar de reproducirse muestre un poster, con este código lo hace muy bien, pero ya no quiero usar jquery. Quiero usar Javascript. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
       <video id="mivideo" controls poster="img/poster.jpg" muted>
                <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
```

```
<script>
  var video = $('#mivideo').get(0);  
        
video.play();
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    v=video.currentSrc;
    video.src='';
    video.src=v;            
});
</script>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que hace el `get(0)` en este caso es lo que haría `[0]` devuelve el primer elemento de los seleccionados por el selector ( **no son los hijos**, aunque los puede incluir, ver [esto](https://jsfiddle.net/wz1275gk/) ), además retorna un elemento del DOM, no el objeto de jquery.

Como estas seleccionando un id, en JavaScript puro siempre va a devolver uno si buscas por id, asi que sería simplemente  `document.getElementById("mivideo")`:

```js
var video = document.getElementById("mivideo");// <-- $('#mivideo').get(0); en Jquery

video.play();
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {

  console.log("Este evento se ejecuta cuando termina el video");
  
});
```

```html
<video id="mivideo" controls poster="img/poster.jpg" muted>
                <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
```

Cuando obtenemos el elemento con `.get()` ya no podemos usar los métodos de jquery, pero si los de JavaScript puro, por eso con lo que retorna `.get()` podemos usar `.play` o `.addEventListener`, sino no podríamos.

El `get` no tiene nada que ver con los segundos, lo que se puede hacer con `<video>` esta [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).

Comment: Gracias Emeeus, los dos anteriores ya habían dado la respuesta correcta, pero tu lo explicaste mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar DOM (Document Object Model) para acceder a cualquier elemento del HTML con JavaScript.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Prueba con `const video = document.getElementById("mivideo");`